# How to install libbz2 in cross compiler g++-arm-linux-gnueabifh on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

I am using arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8 on an amd64 machine to cross compile boost targeting ARM 32-bit architecture. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

It fails to build lib libboost_iostreams because libbz2 does not comes with the compiler. Following is the error detail,

/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

Having a hard time figure out how to install this libbz2 for arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8. Did not find much document online. Need some help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Standard checklist for cross-linking libraries: Do you have libbz2 already installed on the target (or a distro which allows you to do easily)? If so, use that (either copy it across, or better, cross-compile with --sysroot pointing at the target filesystem). Otherwise, just [grab the source](http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html) and cross-compile it! Check the makefile(s) to see whether they allow for a cross-compiler prefix or you have to edit the $CC etc. variables yourself, and don't expect any executable self-tests to pass ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd install libbz2-1.0:armhf from Debian jessie repository.

Actually, it is present in the Ubuntu repositories too.

Configure package manager to manage ARM packages:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

Ubuntu 14.04 codename is 'trusty', so add ARM repositories for trusty by adding the line to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports trusty main
```

Then update package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install libbz2 for ARM (but abort if it asks to remove any packages):

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:armhf
```

If `apt-get` asks to remove half of the system in order to install something big like libc6:armhf, libgcc:armhf, build-essential:armhf etc. then there is a dependency resolution session ahead. There is no precise guide to that.

Also, one minor thing: you may want to add `[arch=amd64,i386]` annotations to all other repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to avoid warnings.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to Debain, can you give me some details, like the commands I need to run or some online document I can follow?

Comment: @CodingForFun15, that package is in the Ubuntu repository too. Updated the answer.